# Exporting map as georeferenced image

Tags: openlayers, export, image

I am using OpenLayers to create a map where I can Zoom and export the view (Following this exemple https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html)
This works fine, but what I need is a georeferenced image (ecw, geotiff) that users can use later on QGIS...

Does anyone knows how can I do this ?

Comment: you need to create a pngw (world file) of the image bounding box

Comment: Thank you for answering. Any trick to do so ? I've been looking for a way to do this but to no avail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [the demo I've made](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/415906d5ac34bf710f8c2fbe42f48201).

It creates a zip with png files, associated pngw (world file) and prj files in a single zip when exporting.

The important part is for writing the pngw with below excerpt.

```
  var currentResolution = view.getResolution();
  var currentExtent = view.calculateExtent(); // Return [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]
  var pngwContent = [
    currentResolution,
    0,
    0,
    -currentResolution,
    currentExtent[0] + currentResolution / 0.5,
    currentExtent[3] - currentResolution / 0.5
  ].join('\n');
```

Then, you open it in QGIS (It's possible without unzipping). It will ask you to choose the projection (in this demo, with EPSG code 3857)

The quick result I got for an overview in QGIS using Wikimedia base maps.

[image: Overview PNG + pngw from OpenLayers QGIS with Wikipedia basemap]